# Missing libkernel32 when trying to compile MEX files

Tags: gcc, g++, mex, msys2

GCC version: 10.3.0

I have a C and C++ project, for which I compile MEX files so it may be run in a MATLAB program. It is compiled in a makefile outside of MATLAB rather than inside MATLAB.

Just a few days ago, I was able to compile and run these MEX files fine. Now (without any known environment or code changes), I get a missing libkernel32 error from the linker.

Here is the compilation step that fails: (the --verbose added just now for testing)

```
g++ -m64 -shared -Wl,-Bsymbolic,--verbose -Wl,--no-undefined -Wl,C:/Progra~1/MATLAB/R2019b/extern/lib/win64/mingw64/exportsmexfileversion.def -o testCreate.mexw64 (several .o files linked here) -pthread -LC:/Progra~1/MATLAB/R2019b/bin/win64 -LC:/Progra~1/MATLAB/R2019b/extern/lib/win64/mingw64 -lmex -lmx
```

(I've commented out the specific .o files linked as it was long and irrelevant in this case)

The linker manages to get fairly far, before hitting this roadblock:

```
attempt to open C:/Progra~1/MATLAB/R2019b/bin/win64/libkernel32.dll.a failed
attempt to open C:/Progra~1/MATLAB/R2019b/bin/win64/kernel32.dll.a failed
attempt to open C:/Progra~1/MATLAB/R2019b/bin/win64/libkernel32.a failed
attempt to open C:/Progra~1/MATLAB/R2019b/bin/win64/kernel32.lib failed
attempt to open C:/Progra~1/MATLAB/R2019b/bin/win64/libkernel32.lib failed
attempt to open C:/Progra~1/MATLAB/R2019b/bin/win64/libkernel32.dll failed
attempt to open C:/Progra~1/MATLAB/R2019b/bin/win64/kernel32.dll failed
attempt to open C:/Progra~1/MATLAB/R2019b/bin/win64\libkernel32.a failed
attempt to open C:/Progra~1/MATLAB/R2019b/extern/lib/win64/mingw64/libkernel32.dll.a failed
attempt to open C:/Progra~1/MATLAB/R2019b/extern/lib/win64/mingw64/kernel32.dll.a failed
attempt to open C:/Progra~1/MATLAB/R2019b/extern/lib/win64/mingw64/libkernel32.a failed
attempt to open C:/Progra~1/MATLAB/R2019b/extern/lib/win64/mingw64/kernel32.lib failed
attempt to open C:/Progra~1/MATLAB/R2019b/extern/lib/win64/mingw64/libkernel32.lib failed
attempt to open C:/Progra~1/MATLAB/R2019b/extern/lib/win64/mingw64/libkernel32.dll failed
attempt to open C:/Progra~1/MATLAB/R2019b/extern/lib/win64/mingw64/kernel32.dll failed
attempt to open C:/Progra~1/MATLAB/R2019b/extern/lib/win64/mingw64\libkernel32.a failed
attempt to open C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.3.0/libkernel32.dll.a failed
attempt to open C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.3.0/kernel32.dll.a failed
attempt to open C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.3.0/libkernel32.a failed
attempt to open C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.3.0/kernel32.lib failed
attempt to open C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw3collect2.exe: error: ld returned 5 exit status
```

Looking online I found [some others](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/411858-lnk1181-cannot-open-input-file-kernel32-lib) who encountered a similar issue, but never found a solution.

I have no idea *where* this libkernal is supposed to be (MSYS, MATLAB, somewhere else?) so I'm not sure what to do.

What I have tried:

- Updating msys packages with `pacman -Syu`
- Re-installing the package that has a libkernel32 via `pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-crt-git` (already installed and up to date, reinstall did not fix it)
- Removing the link to pthread, as I don't believe it's used anymore. (In case it was somehow the one requiring libkernel) - no joy.

Update:

- Adding the following line: `-LC:/msys64/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib` has stopped the immediate failure, but the linker just fails slightly afterwards, with:

```
attempt to open C:/msys64/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libmoldname.dll.a failed
attempt to open C:/msys64/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/moldname.dll.a failed
attempt to open C:/msys64/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libmoldname.a succeeded
C:/msys64/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libmoldname.a
attempt to open C:/Progra~1/MATLAB/R2019b/bin/win64/libmingwex.dll.a failed
attempt to open C:/Progra~1/MATLAB/R2019b/bin/win64/mingwex.dll.a failed
attempt to open C:/Progra~1/MATLAB/R2019b/bin/win64/libmingwex.a failed
attempt to open C:/Progra~1/MATLAB/R2019b/bin/win64/mingwex.lib failed
attempt to open C:/Progra~1/MATLAB/R2019b/bin/win64/libmingwex.lib failed
attempt to open C:/Progra~1/MATLAB/R2019b/bin/win64/libmingwex.dll failed
attempt to open C:/Progra~1/MATLAB/R2019b/bin/win64/mingwex.dll failed
attempt to open C:/Progra~1/MATLAB/R2019b/bin/win64\libmingwex.a failed
attempt to open C:/Progra~1/MATLAB/R2019b/extern/lib/win64/mingw64/libmingwex.dll.a failed
attempt to open C:/Progra~1/MATLAB/R2019b/extern/lib/win64/mingw64/mingwex.dll.a failed
attempt to open C:/Progra~1/MATLAB/R2019b/extern/lib/win64/mingw64/libmingwex.a failed
attempt to open C:/Progra~1/MATLAB/R2019b/extern/lib/win64/mingw64/mingwex.lib failed
attempt to open C:/Progra~1/MATLAB/R2019b/extern/lib/win64/mingw64/libmingwex.lib failed
attempt to open C:/Progra~1/MATLAB/R2019b/extern/lib/win64/mingw64/libmingwex.dll failed
attempt to open C:/Progra~1/MATLAB/R2019b/extern/lib/win64/mingw64/mingwex.dll failed
attempt to open C:/Progra~1/MATLAB/R201collect2.exe: error: ld returned 5 exit status
make: *** [Makefile:151: testCreate.mexw64] Error 1
```

This is odd, because if you look at the one before (libmoldname) it correctly looks in C:/msys64 but doesn't look there for this new missing file. (Not that this was neccesary for the last several years, so no idea why I'd need to link that path now *anyways*)

EDIT: That last line from also looks broken (C:/Progra~1/MATLAB/R201collect2.exe), the path is wrong. Visual bug, or something else?

Comment: Do you have any of the searched for files in a different location ?

Comment: I am on Windows without the ability to install a convenient search tool like Everything. Is there a fast way to search for where those files might be?

Comment: Use Explorer navigate to a sensible folder eg `C:/msys64` and type into the search box ( F3 if you can't see it)

Comment: I do have a libkernel32.a under C:/msys64/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libkernel32.a (which is not in the paths it checked, from the log)

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the fault was with the `make clean`. Awhile back part of the source got moved into its own folder, which `make clean` doesn't clean.

The .o files inside were old, or from a different architecture completely, so caused a mess. Removing them and re-building fixed all issues.